# Wiremock: how to verify if a query string parameter has a value greater than a specific number

Tags: wiremock

We have a requirement to return different responses based on the numeric value of a query string parameter.
I found that it's possible to use regex, but that would require us to rewrite that regex each time that specific number would change.

Ideally, we would like something like:

```
if paramValue < 10 response: "less than 10"
else if paramValue < 234 response: "less then 234 and greater than 10"
else if paramValue > 815 response: "greater than 815".
```